# gradle war rename file regular exp not working

Tags: regex, gradle, rename, war

Gradle war: rename files not working with regular expr.

```
war {
   into "foo"

   from ("hello/world") {
      include "bar/config/*.xml"
       // remove bar/ in the path
      rename '(.*)/bar/config/(.*)', '$1/config/$2'

      // tried
      // rename 'bar/config/(.*)', 'config/$1'

   }


}
```

Trying to rename

```
foo/bar/config/*.xml -> foo/config/*.xml
```

The entry path was not changed inside the war.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rename` is operating on the file **name**, not the full path. To change the path you'll need access to a [`FileCopyDetails`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileCopyDetails.html) object. One way to do that is with `filesMatching()`:

```
war {
    from('hello/world') {
        includeEmptyDirs = false
        include 'bar/config/*.xml'
        filesMatching('**/*.xml') {
            it.path = it.path.replace('bar/', '')
        }
    }
}
```